# PHP syntax within PHP Array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have this array:

> ```
> $output = array( 'test' => "<b>Blah blah</b>",
>                  'test2' => "<b>Hello World</b> 
>                               if ($foo = 4){ 
>                                   echo "!";       }",
> ```
>
> );

How can I throw in any PHP statement within the array?

Example: "test2" with the if statement above.

**Update (Here's the actual code I'm trying to throw into the array):**

```
> <select id='user1' name='user1'>
>                                   <option selected disabled>Select User</option>";
>                           for($x=0;$x<$arrlength2;$x++){
>                           if ((isset($_POST['user1'])) && ($_POST['user1'] == $arraydt2[$x]))
>                           {
>                               echo "<option selected='" . $arraydt2[$x] . "' value=\"$arraydt[$x]\">$arraydt2[$x]</option>";}
>                           else    
>                               echo "<option value=\"$arraydt2[$x]\">$arraydt2[$x]</option>";
>                           }
>                           echo "</select>
```

Comment: Gotta ask: Why? Code sample for a blog or something? In any case you have to escape it like any other string.

Comment: Using AJAX to display this data but this external page is doing all the work. I plan on having a for loop to populate a dropdown within the array.

Comment: You can't have code in string context. (With some exceptions. But I don't think it's advisable to tell, unless you are versed with the basic syntax constraints.)

Comment: OK there's a lot of confusion about whether or not you want to *run* this code or have it treated as a string, please clarify.

Comment: In php 5.3 you're even able to create an array of anonymous functions if you ever need something more complex http://www.php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: I've updated my question with what I'm actually trying to display.

Comment: Just assign all that HTML to a variable before creating your array. Make sense?

Comment: Just build your array within the for loop... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such code to achieve the same:

```
$output = array( 'test' => "<b>Blah blah</b>",
                 'test2' => "<b>Hello World</b>".(($foo == 4 ) ? '!' : '') );
```

It's called ternary operator. More about it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

If you want to achieve result as in modified question you should simple assign $value to variable and then $assign it to array as below:

```
$variable = '';

if ($a == '...') {
   $variable .= '...';
}
if ($b == '...' and $c != '...') {
   $variable .='...';
}
$output = array( 'test' => "<b>Blah blah</b>",
                 'test2' => $variable);

);
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the actual code I'm trying to execute within the array. I don't it'll be possible now :(.

Comment: I've added another solution to answer in your case

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you are trying to accomplish, but given your last update, it sounds like you don't want to put `php syntax` into your array, you want to put dynamically generated html into your array. Maybe something like this:

```
$output = array();
$output['test'] = "<b>Blah blah</b>";
$output['test2'] = "<b>Hello World</b>";

if ($foo == 4) {

    $output['test2'] .= "<select id='user1' name='user1'>";
    $output['test2'] .= "<option selected disabled>Select User</option>";

    for($x=0;$x<$arrlength2;$x++) {
        if ((isset($_POST['user1'])) && ($_POST['user1'] == $arraydt2[$x])) {
            $output['test2'] .= "<option selected='" . $arraydt2[$x] . "' value=\"$arraydt[$x]\">$arraydt2[$x]</option>";}
        else    
            $output['test2'] .= "<option value=\"$arraydt2[$x]\">$arraydt2[$x]</option>";
    }

    $output['test2'] .= "</select>";

}
```

Comment: The first part of question has nothing to do with the second updated part.

Comment: @ElefantPhace What do you mean? Of course it does. He has an array, with data. Then, if his conditional is true, he wants to add more data to an element. The second part clarifies that the data he wants to add is a dynamically generated `<select>`

Comment: You should take another look at the op and read the comments on that and the first answer. The first part was just an example of what he was wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = array();
for.....{
    $output[] = "your content here."
}
```

Gives you an idea of what you should be doing.